# Couldn't get any data from API

Tags: api, flutter, get

I am facing a problem to get data from API. I think here 'data' in json API is creating a problem. Here is my json API Link: https://boimarket.abirahsan.com/api/v1/categories/1/books

*here is my model.dart-*

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String base_url = "https://boimarket.abirahsan.com/api/v1/categories/1/books";
Future<Book> fetchBooks() async {
  var response = await http.get(base_url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    return Book.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Book');
  }
}

class Book {
  final String name;
  final String author;
  final String genreClass;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String pdf;
  final String html;
  final String description;
  final String category;

  Book({
    this.name,
    this.author,
    this.genreClass,
    this.imgUrl,
    this.description,
    this.html,
    this.pdf,
    this.category,
  });

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      name: json['name'],
      imgUrl: json['image'],
      pdf: json['pdf'],
      html: json['html'],
      description: json['description'],
      author: json['author'],
      genreClass: json['genre_class'],
      category: json['category'],
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my storybooks.dart -

```
import 'package:boimarket/booksdescription.dart';
import 'package:boimarket/model/model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:draggable_scrollbar/draggable_scrollbar.dart';

class StoryBooksCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController controller;
  final List<Book> storybooks;
  StoryBooksCategory({Key key, @required this.controller, this.storybooks})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StoryBooksCategoryState createState() => _StoryBooksCategoryState();
}

class _StoryBooksCategoryState extends State<StoryBooksCategory> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final Color _whiteCream = Color.fromRGBO(250, 245, 228, 1);
    final Color _darkBlue = Color.fromRGBO(0, 68, 69, 1);
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        width: _width / 1.1,
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: fetchBooks().asStream(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  LinearProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: _whiteCream,
                  ),
                  Text("Loading"),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var mydata = snapshot.data;
              print(mydata.length);
              return DraggableScrollbar.rrect(
                controller: widget.controller,
                backgroundColor: _darkBlue,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: widget.controller,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: mydata.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              BookDescription(storyBooksValue: mydata[index]),
                        );
                        Navigator.push(context, route);
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 20.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: _width / 1.1,
                          height: _height / 4,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: _whiteCream,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(5.0),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black26,
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                )
                              ]),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 4,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Card(
                                    elevation: 10.0,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                        fadeOutCurve: Curves.easeInCubic,
                                        placeholder:
                                            'assets/images/bookshelf.jpg',
                                        image: mydata[index].imgUrl == null
                                            ? 'assets/images/bookshelf.jpg'
                                            : mydata[index].imgUrl,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 6,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          "বইয়ের নামঃ ",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Flexible(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "${mydata[index].name}",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          "লেখকঃ ",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Flexible(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "${mydata[index].author}",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          "বইয়ের ধরণঃ ",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Flexible(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "${mydata[index].genreClass}",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.error_outline),
                  Text("Somthing Went to wrong"),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and now I am not getting any data from here. Where is the problem in my code? How can I fix this ?

Comment: It looks like your api isn't working: `boimarket.abirahsan.com’s server IP address could not be found`

Comment: first check your url bro :)

Comment: @Er1 Now this url is  ok

Comment: @ParthPitroda please check it now

Comment: @AbirAhsan its still not working

Comment: I got this answer from @Richard Heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, your JSON has a `data` tag - and that contains an array of books (not just one). Since you are getting more than one book, you need a `List`.

```
Future<List<Book>> fetchBooks() async {
  var response = await http.get(base_url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var decoded = json.decode(response.body);
    return decoded['data'].map<Book>((b) => Book.fromJson(b)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Book');
  }
}
```

Also your category is an integer, so change that in `Book` to:

```
class Book {
  final String name;
  final String author;
  final String genreClass;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String pdf;
  final String html;
  final String description;
  final int category; //<- this is an int
```

Comment: Also, in your widget you might want to change to a regular `FutureBuilder`, as there's no stream.

Comment: ohh it's working. But Do you explain that,  what's problem if I convert future builder to StreamBuilder ?

Comment: You should use a `StreamBuilder` when you are getting a stream of events - for example from a web socket or similar. Your HTTPS get isn't going to be a stream - just a single result (list of books), so use `FutureBuilder`